# How can I use two resources with the same alias (modx)?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I am using friendly URLS, but Modx doesn't allow to use the same alias name, even if it is in another folder, like for example:

```
http://www.mypage/friends/blog
```

and

```
http://www.mypage/community/blog
```

is not possible. I get the error message:

```
Resource is already using the URI
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3):

In **System Settings** make sure **Use Friendly Alias Path** is set to **Yes**.